# Intelephense not recognising parent theme functions

Tags: theme-development, child-theme

So i have the intelephense ext on VS code, and i have managed to have it recognise ACF functions by downloading the stubs to my computer. however, it does not recognise parent theme functions, understrap. has anyone any insight into this, even if i set the sftp path to the wp-content folder, it still does not recognise understrap functions, ( parent theme ).

I have tried adding the path in the intelephense environment paths, still doesnt help. I think i am missing a step. do i need to add something else to settings.json?